# Sending forms clears the Get parameters

Tags: django, django-templates, forms

When I click on the link

`<a href="?page={{request.GET.page}}&order_by=counter__service__name_service&sort={{ sort_type }}&from_date={{request.GET.from_date}}&from_date={{request.GET.to_date}}&type_water={{request.GET.type_water}}">`

all the parameters are saved as both forms and the rest, but when I try to also keep the parameters in the form action method

`<form class="row justify-content-around" id="searchform" action="{% url 'history_application' %}?page={{request.GET.page}}&order_by={{request.GET.order_by}}&sort={{request.GET.sort}}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">`

it removes them (URL: `history/?type_water=hot&from_date=&to_date=`).

Why parameters do not remain in the query?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding a hidden input.

After reading https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm found that everything that is after `?` is replaced by the form elements.